# Win 10 system_service_exception and BSOD after enabling virtualization (vt-x) in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, bsod, vt-x, hardware-virtualization

I want to enable Intel Virtualization Technology via the updated BIOS of my ASUS ROG STRIX Z270I motherboard, but each time I enable it, Windows crashes to blue screen of death with a `system_service_exception` error.

I chased this bug down as far as I could reviewing the Event Viewer system logs, Googling, removing software and drivers, etc. but it still persisted. I could boot into safemode with virtualization enabled, just not regular Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be many problems with Hyper-V, and although I did not have Hyper-V installed (you can check this by typing Hyper-V in the Win 10 search bar, selecting "Turn Windows Features On or Off", then scrolling down to Hyper-V) it seems that a hypervisor was still running on bootup.

[Anthony J. Celaya's answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119095204/http://www.poweronplatforms.com:80/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8) from poweronplatforms.com finally allowed me to enable virtualization via the BIOS and start up Win 10 v1709 build 16299.334:

1. Start a command prompt with administrator privileges
2. Run `bcdedit` and check the status of `hypervisorlaunchtype`
3. If `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to auto, run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
4. Reboot and enable virtualization in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I chased down something like this on my ROG ASUS running Win10 after I changed the "Core Isolation" configuration following a freeze/suspected virus.

- Turning on Core Isolation Protection *(Settings > Windows Security > Device Security)*: 
   Results with a BSOD (driver was similar to `iobc.sys`) for ROG Gaming Center and Asus/Intel XTU. Core Isolation [could be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000006/vt-x-isnt-available-no-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-10) in conflict with Intel VT-X.

**Turning off Core Isolation Protection:** 
 Needs to be done with one the instructions below after it is turned on within Device Security

- [How to turn Core Isolation on / off](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104025-turn-off-core-isolation-memory-integrity-windows-10-a.html)
- [Disable Core Isolation Setting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/disable-core-isolation-setting/55969812-d407-4c02-9153-e0e7e25a165f) 
   I made the folloring registry change and rebooted:

  ```powershell
  [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity]
  "Enabled"=dword:00000000
  ```

Answer (score 0):

#### BSOD when turning on Virtualization.

##### My Machine:

- Windows 10 (Host)
- Asus ROG MAXIMUS X CODE (LGA1151),
- Intel Core i7 8700K (Coffee Lake),
- GeForce RTX 3070 Ti

I had this setup before but got deleted b/c of my stupidity.

So I know this setup would work again.

Installed Oracle VM, then XP OS (64 bit) as guest.
I run an older version of AutoCad, it won't run on newer systems.

After all this installed, Enabling Virtualization, booted, BSOD.

What I did:

- **Disable Virtualization**, got my machine back.
  Installed latest graphic driver from Nvidia, make sure everything is good with your new Nvidia driver.
  (not sure if this had anything to do with the fix).
  Back in Bios, **Disable** **SECURE BOOT,** **DO NOT DELETE YOUR KEYS.**
- Reboot, make sure everything is OK.
- Go back into Bios, enable Virtualization.
- Hyper-V is disabled.
- Reboot and this worked for me.

Why did this work? I have no clue. Maybe someone else can chime in and explain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).